# Delete buffer and go back to netrw

Tags: vim, netrw

When I open a file using vim's file browser *netrw*, I want get back to netrw after deleting the file buffer. Here's what I'm doing:

```
vim .
```

Open a file with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then delete the buffer:

```
:bd
```

But this puts me in a new unnamed buffer. I might be wrong, but I thought getting back to netrw used to be the standard behavior. Was there a change? Is there a variable to control this?

The difference shows up with `vim .` and `:ls!`:

```
# Output (good)
1  h   "~/"                           line 1
2u%a-  "[No Name]"                    line 8

# Output (bad)
2u%a-  "~/"                           line 8
```

Comment: Just tried it on my own Ubuntu 20, Vim 8.1. It works as you expected, with `:bd` closing the buffer and then returning me to the netrw.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on `8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 01 2021 01:51:08)` (Debian Bullseye).

Comment: @wxz How about: `vim .` → select file → `:bd` → select file → `:bd`?

Comment: I followed the steps you listed and this time it did take me to a blank, unnamed buffer.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess it works once or never.